# Access join causing error in results

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have found that the results from my Access query do not reconcile to the source data table. Through process of elimination I have determined the issue has to do with my table join, but I don't understand why or how to resolve it. To keep this simple, I have eliminated all, but the one field and one join from query that where I have found the issue.

Query 1: has a join to another table, but I have simplified the query so that no fields are returned and there are no conditions in the query. I am simply summing a single field from "Data" and ignoring "State_Details".

```
SELECT Sum(Data.[Total Amount]) AS [SumOfTotal Amount]
FROM Data LEFT JOIN State_Details ON (Data.BenefitsState = State_Details.BENEFITS_STATE) 
AND (Data.ClientNum = State_Details.CLIENT_NUM);
```

Query 2: I remove the join and perform the same sum.

```
SELECT Sum(Data.[Total Amount]) AS [SumOfTotal Amount]
FROM Data;
```

The two queries return slightly different results. I have not come across this before and don't know why this join isn't working right or how to resolve. Any insights would be appreciated. Note: I am not very familiar with SQL. I use the Design view in Access, but can do some basic reading and modifying of SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would this surprise you?  Clearly it is saying that there are duplicates in `State_Details.BenefitsState`.

Run the following query:

```
select BenefitsState, count(*)
from State_Details
group by BenefitsState
having count(*) > 1;
```

Another possibility exists if `[Total Amount]` is stored as a *floating point* type and the error is really, really small.  The order of evaluation of floating point operations can make a difference, particularly when the range of values is large.